# Why can't my laptop detect my S3 phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb-connection-mode

I want to upload pictures from my S3 to laptop.

There is no problem with my cable and laptop because my phone was able to charge when I connect my phone with the laptop. However, my laptop didn't detect any device when I connect my phone in with the cable. Hence, I am unable to upload images / add songs to my Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: Possible answer here

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/note-3-cannot-connect-to-windows-7

Comment: For Windows OS, download and install Samsung USB Drivers for Mobile Devices from [here](https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/9618830/Samsung_USB_Drivers_for_Mobile_Devices_v1.5.33_Installer), or [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11633550#post11633550). Then, enable USB Debugging on your S3. Next, connect your S3 to Windows via the USB cable and you're good to go.

Comment: [This post](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-That-Won%27t-Connect-to-Your-PC) helps me. In short: just remove your SIM card and battery, wait for about 30 seconds and put it back.

Comment: @sameer the post has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has very bad connections on that line of phones (S3, N2) I know this because I have a Galaxy Note 2 and about 6 months ago it was doing the same thing, then eventually it stopped charging all together. I also have a friend with S3 and the exact same thing had happened, except it wouldn't charge(luckily his was still in warranty).

You need to check if it is being detected in another PC, if not, the connection is broken.If you really really need to be able to plug it into a PC, you will have to buy a [replacement charger dock port](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Charging-Charger-Dock-Port-Flex-Cable-For-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-2-II-N7100-/371009882424?pt=US_Cell_Phone_Replacement_Parts_Tools&hash=item5661e98938).

Or you can use [airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) to wirelessly transfer files to an from your PC over a wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the correct USB drivers for the Samsung Galaxy S3? If not, download and install Samsung Kies.

You also need to make sure USB tethering is disabled: `Settings > Wireless & networks > More > Tethering & portable hotspot`. Then, check USB settings: `Settings > Device > Storage > Menu > USB computer connection`.

[Source](https://support.google.com/android/answer/1650161?hl=en).

Comment: So now it needs drivers for Windows even if you just want to access the storage? Didn't know that MTP was that bad. Besides, the page you link as source doesn't even mention the word "driver" -- it basically says "plug in the USB cable and enjoy": *When you connect your phone to the USB port on your computer, its USB storage is mounted as a drive and appears on your computer screen.* -> the word is "drive", not "driver" :)

Comment: @Izzy Windows users still have to install USB drivers for the phone, so that MTP / PTP will work correctly.

Comment: OMG. I see, MTP is a real improvement over UMS. With UMS, one can simply plug the device in any Linux/Mac/Windows computer, and it's detected like any USB stick. MTP doesn't seem to work out-of-the-box anywhere -- and I know quite a few people who'd rather kill me than letting me install "some driver" to their Windows computer, as I'm not the vendor and they're afraid for their warranty or whatever. Ooops </rant> :) So why doesn't that Google help page mention this? To me it looks like "Plug and enjoy, no drivers needed". Strange.

Comment: @Izzy UMS can be dangerous, because it exposes every file/folder to the regular user. With MTP, the user sees only what is "safe" to touch. They can still make mistakes and delete stuff, but it shouldn't be dangerous enough to brick the phone.

Comment: Yeah yeah, sorry. I didn't want to start discussing their pros and cons here (there are both; if you like to, we can do that in chat -- but here's the wrong place, my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

We people have issues like that too. I am not so sure about Samsung S3, but I am sure about Android, I had an android phone, whose Drivers were perfect! I have checked for Drivers by the CD that came.

The issue is either not because of the cable, because if it charges well then it must connect to PC too, then where is the issue?

Here are the two major reasons:

1. Please check that your USB supports fast data transfer (USB 2.0), because Android would try to connect to a faster one.
2. Please note that there is alot of issues with Android itself too. Like many other apps running. When you connect to the USB, you get a popup that connecting usb storage would stop many other apps bla bla. So that is a reason too as android does not want to stop some personal apps from working. For this, you can restart the phone. This way this issue would be resolved, I have checked this one more than 5 times.

And USB tethering is just related to Internet, you won't get to use Internet on your connected PC, if you're having the tethering settings turned off. So that has nothing to do with the USB Storage!

**Tip:** When android gets the favourable conditions it would itself show the Connect dialog, otherwise you might need to change the port of USB you are connection too. Ory try **the might Restart-the-phone trick.** This way, you will get the images there! There is no other issue, I have been facing this issue for a long time. Then I caught the errors, the basic one is the USB port, then the Android apps; for that you can restart the phone.

USB drivers are installed by Default while you're connecting the device by general. In Windows OS (That's the only one I use) you would see the popup saying Installing Device Drivers, if that goes perfectly, then you can connect the device. Otherwise the only is this! Or there is a bug in the ROM (if you installed a custom ROM).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when I restarted my phone. After that, it automatically detected my phone from my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Few Samsung phones have issues with their micro USB ports. Even my Galaxy Nexus has had this problem. The easiest way to fix it it use a pin(something shard) and push the micro USB port of the phone slowly and very carefully to the screen.

I suggest you to take it to a authorized service center though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have connected the device as PTP but not MTP. Follow these steps to connect through MTP-

1. First connect the USB cable to your laptop then scroll the notification bar down and you will have USB icon box ,Click on that and change your connection to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) to transfer files in Windows.
2. Now that you have the proper settings you can connect to the Laptop. As soon as you connect your laptop the Windows Operating System will try to identify the hardware(Mobile device) connected and install its drivers which would be already present in the Operating system thus making it a plug n play Operating System.
3. Else if you still are unable to change the setting then visit this [link](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Samsung-Galaxy-S5.how_to_change_the_usb_connection_options_on_my)
   it has a complete description along with pictures

Else if not available then you need to update your drivers either through the windows update >USB Drivers for Samsung or manually download the drivers from the Samsung site.